# ArrayOutOfBoundsException in nested for loop

Tags: java

I'm doing a tutorial on a basic 2D tower defense game, and we're basically trying to fill a window with a bunch of tiles, but I get an ArrayOurOfBoundsException here, and I don't get why!

```
    map = new Tile[20][12];
    for (int i=0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; i < map[i].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = new Tile(i*64, j*64, 64, 64, TileType.Grass);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int j=0; i < map[i].length; j++)
//            ↑
```

That's an ***i***, not a ***j***.

So maybe you need to use a different font, or use a different letter for your inner loops.